# Select items and transfer selected items to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I am creating an app, and am having difficulties trying to create a way where the user selects multiple images, which will then be passed on to another screen. Could I please get some help on this? 
Much will be appreciated.

So, the way my app works is that, the user selects multiple items, then there should be an add button or a save button, that will get the selected items and display them to another screen. The items have a value which are Images, not text. This is purely the reason why I asked the question here because most of the React-Native tutorials include values based on text, rather than Images.

The problem I am having, is trying to figure out a way for the user to select multiple items, and clicking a save button, which will in return transfer all of the "selected items" to another screen to be display there. Much like a viewer.

```html
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, AppRegistry, FlatList, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import flatListData from '../database';
 
class FlatListItem extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'FirstScreen!'
})

  render() {          
    return (        
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection:'column',                                
        }}>            
            <View style={{  
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection:'row',
            }}>            
                <View style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection:'column',   
                        height: 100                 
                    }}>            
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen')} >
                              <Image source={{uri: this.props.item.imageUrl}}
                              style={{width: 100, height: 100, margin: 5}}></Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>             
            </View>
            <View style={{
                height: 1,
                backgroundColor:'white'                            
            }}>
        
            </View>
      </View>
    );
}
}

class FirstScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'First Screen'
})

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 22}}>
          <FlatList 
              data={flatListData}
              renderItem={({item, index})=>{
                  //console.log(`Item = ${JSON.stringify(item)}, index = ${index}`);
                  return (
                  <FlatListItem item={item} index={index}>

                  </FlatListItem>);
              }}
              >

          </FlatList>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default example;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flatListItem: {
      color: 'white',
      padding: 10,
      fontSize: 16,  
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by passing images to another screen? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid that without a [mcve] and a very clear description of what you're trying to accomplish, it's not possible to assist. Can you post your code by editing the question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any sample code, so I will try to suggest a way to handle via pseudocode

You can abstract out the list of images into a centralized helper class, then you render from this helper class for user to select.

Now when user have selected one of the image, you just need to capture the ID or any unique identifier, and pass it to second screen.

On this second screen, just using this ID/unique identifier that you've received and search it from the aforementioned centralized helper class and render it.

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you could demonstrate it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two things to figure out;

- one is keeping track of what items a user has selected on your image selection screen
- sending the data back between screens

Looks like you are most likely using `react-navigation` based on your example so the simplest solution would be to take advantage of React's `state` and use `react-navigation`'s parameter passing between screens.

With `react-navigation` you can use the second argument in `navigation.navigate` to pass parameters/callbacks to the other screen. So you can navigate to a screen and pass a callback to it as such.

```
...
this.props.navigation.navigate(
  'ItemSelectionScreen',
  { onSubmit: (items) => { /* Do something with items */ } }
)
...
```

And here is a basic example of a selection screen with some comments to explain how it works.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});

class ItemSelectionScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = () => props.navigation.getParam('onSubmit'); // Keep the passed callback once we have navigated to this screen

    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [] // Our initial selectedItems (empty)
    };
  }

  handleToggle = (item, isSelected) => {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;

    this.setState({ selectedItems: isSelected ? selectedItems.filter(ent => ent !== item) : [...selectedItems, item] }); // Toggle if an item is selected
  };

  handleSubmitAndExit = () => {
    const { onSubmit } = this;
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;

    onSubmit(selectedItems); // Pass your selectedItems back to the other screen
    this.props.navigation.goBack(); // And exit the screen
  };

  handleExit = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(); // Exit the screen without calling onSubmit
  };

  renderItem = (item, index) => {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;

    const isSelected = selectedItems.some(ent => ent === item); // Determine if an item is selected

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.handleToggle(item, isSelected)}>
        <Text>{`${isSelected ? 'X' : 'O'} ${item}`}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {['item1', 'item2', 'item3'].map(this.renderItem)}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleSubmitAndExit}>
          <Text>Submit and Exit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleExit}>
          <Text>Exit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ItemSelectionScreen;
```

Good luck and hope this was helpful.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you for that. Appreciate it. One more question, the selected items, I would like to be imported/shown in another screen so how would I do that? Also, the items that you have defined are in text format, and I would only want to pass in Images...

Comment: if you are navigating back to that screen then you could use the solution provided above. If you are navigating to another screen you can pass it as a param when doing `navigation.navigate`. However if you find yourself passing params from screen to screen and want data available across the whole app, you might want to look into hooking up `redux` into your project.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to look at the documentation for redux.